# Cambiar contraseña de usuario teniendo solo el hash

Tags: linux

Buenas tardes a todos!

¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar una contraseña de un usuario en Linux únicamente teniendo el hash de esta? 
Es decir, en otra máquina Linux he generado una contraseña para un usuario, copio el hash del fichero /etc/shadow y lo pego en la otra máquina, sería suficiente? 
He hecho pruebas y no me ha funcionado por lo que entiendo que no. 
Esto lo hago porque necesito pasar ese hash a terceras personas para que lo apliquen en un Puppet y no quiero pasarles la contraseña de root.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Es una pregunta muy amplia. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código que hayas intentado y 
los errores que tengas. Recuerda [visitar el tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber más del funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: Buenos días @MauricioAriasOlave No puedo añadir el código porque es un HASH privado y no puedo compartirlo. Es una pregunta general ya que quería entender mejor como podría implementar un hash en vez de una contraseña. La respuesta de Trauma me ha servido. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Depende** de la configuración *PAM* de ambos sistemas, que, en mi `Ubuntu`, está almacenada en `/etc/pam.d/passwd`, que a su vez se limita a cargar `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, y nos sugiere consultar `man pam_unix`.

En dicho `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, la opción importante es

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

Si **Ambos** sistemas usan la misma configuración, **es** tan fácil como sugieres: copiar los caracteres entre el primer y el segundo `:`, quedando el `/etc/shadow` tal que así:

```
...
user1:ñlakjsdfñasljfñajfslf:17086...
...
user2:ñlakjsdfñasljfñajfslf:19786...
...
```

En ese ejmplo, **ambos** usuarios comparten la misma contraseña.

También conviene comprobar el `/etc/passwd`, solo para asegurarnos de que ambos usuarios tienen activas las contraseñas usando el sistema *shadow*:

```
...
user1:x:1997:...
...
user2:x:1998:...
```

Es este archivo, lo importante es la `x`, que indica que para ese usuario se utiliza el sistema *shadow*.

En caso de que los sistemas **no usen** la misma configuración, la cosa se complica bastante. Podrías *reconfigurar* uno de ellos, pero eso implica la eliminación de las contraseñas actuales para establecer otras con la nueva configuración.

**EDITO**

Existen *alternativas* a lo que pretendes: usar `sudo`, usar `ssh` con clave pública/privada, ...

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de mucho!

Answer (score 1):

Traspasar el hash de una contraseña contradice el sentido de usar un hash. Si das acceso con el hash directo abres tu sistema a cualquier ataque tipo "man in the middle", donde terceros filtran el hash y lo usan para acceder tu sistema en forma no autorizado.

Comment: Gracias por la info. Son máquinas internas lo que se busca es crear una máquina base la cual se genera un Puppet y se despliega a las demás. Nosotros lo que haremos es que si queremos cambiar las password en planta se modifican en esa máquina y se lanza el Puppet. El problema es que hay gente de Dev que también puede tocar, y en realidad es quien cambia las password, que no nos interesan que tengan las de root, solo el hash, por eso.